# Automated vision-based cyclist detection android app

Tags: android, ocr

Last week i have chosen my major project. It is a vision based system to monitor cyclists in time trial events passing certain points on the course. It should detect the bright yellow race number on a cyclist's back and extract the number from it, and besides record the time.
I done some research about it and i decided to use Tesseract Android Tools by Robert Theis called Tess Two. To speed up the process of recognizing the text i want to use a fact that the number is mend to be extracted from bright (yellow) rectangle on the cyclist back and to focus the actual OCR only on it. I have not found any piece of code or any ideas how to detect the geometric figures with specific color. Thank you for any help. And sorry if i made any mistakes I am pretty new on this website.

Answer (score 1):

Where are the images coming from? I ask because I was asked to provide some technical help for the design of a similar application (we were working with footballer's shirts) and I can tell you that you'll have a few problems:

- Use a high quality video feed rather than rely on a couple of digital camera images.
  The number will almost certainly be 'curved' or distorted because of the movement of the rider and being able to use a series of images will sometimes allow you to work out what number it really is based on a series of 'false reads'
- Train for the font you're using but also apply as much logic as you can (if the numbers are always two digits and never start with '9', use this information to help you get the right number
- If you have the luxury of being able to position the camera (we didn't!), I would have thought your ideal spot would be above the rider and looking slightly forward so you can capture their back with the minimum of distortions.
- We found that merging several still-frames from the video into one image gave us the best overall image of the number - however, the technology that was used for this was developed by a third-party and they do not want to release it, I'm afraid :(

Good luck!